# Persistent storage maximum size reached while the length of storage is 0

Tags: html, local-storage

I got a "Persistent storage maximum size reached" error when I call the following code:

```
    localStorage.setItem('key', 1);
```

But when I get the length attribute of the localStorage, the result is 0:

```
    localStorage.length; // returns 0
```

The problem occurred on my Firefox 13.0.1 Mac version

Comment: You have to allow local storage in some browser I dont remember which though

Comment: The local storage is already allowed, the problem only occurred in a specific domain.

Comment: Assuming you haven't stored data elsewhere on the domain filling up the quota, this sounds like a browser issue. Have you tried try and catch? Reinstalling firefox?

Comment: I think it's browser's bug too. I have tried reinstall but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

The `localStorage/sessionStorage` limit can be set to zero. Use the following process to check it:

- Open the config URL: about:config
- Type the storage query in the search: `storage`
- Check the quota value: `dom.storage.default_quota`
- Change it to a non-zero value

**References**

- [Dom.storage.default quota - MozillaZine Knowledge Base](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Dom.storage.default_quota)

Comment: Perfect answer, don't know why this answer had no upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve this issue by clearing essentially everything under: 
Preferences -> Privacy -> Clear Your Recent History (Clear All History)

I ended up checking all checkboxes and hit Clear Now.

We had the same issue where some data that was supposed to be stored in localStorage was not getting populated because of some other items in storage.  This cleared it up.  I imagine perhaps it was cookies, but I'm not sure at this point.

Comment: That's a really crappy workaround. Nobody wants to lose all history etc.

Comment: For me it was enough to clear the cache only. Obviously, this doesn't solve the root cause of the problem though.